# Why doesn't Xcode displays all the files in my Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift-package-manager

In macOS Ventura, on Xcode 14.2, I cannot seem to get my project to see all the classes from my Swift library's files.

For example:
• PoopersLib has both "PoopersLib.swift", "Fudge.swift" in it's "Sources/PooperLib" folder. They each have classes and variables. It was created on rPi using Swift 5.1. It compiles just fine by itself both in command line and XCode, rPi on macOS.

• In "MyApp", using either Finder or File > Add Packages, I've added PoopersLib to my macOS app project, making sure to include them in the app's "Target" section with the other libs and frameworks.

• Added "import PoopersLib" to relevant file.

However, I fail on any code that uses any classes or variables from Fudge.swift, like `init(number: Int)`. I receive a "Cannot find 'Fudge' in scope" like the file doesn't exist. Everything in PoopersLib.swift works just fine.

```
_ = PoopersLib()
_ = Fudge(number:5)
```

I have also tried manually defining the files in the Package.swift like this:

```
        .target(
            name: "PoopersLib",
            dependencies: [],
            sources: [
                "PoopersLib.swift",
                "Fudge.swift",
            ]),
```

I still get the same error "Cannot find 'Fudge' in scope".

What am I missing in importing or adding Swift Package to my XCode app? Or do I need to manually drag(copy) each file into my app?

Comment: `Fudge` is public, right?

Comment: OMG, this was it. THX!!! ...when you spend all day fixing the problem, but the thing was unplugged the whole time!

Answer (score -1):

Oh duh... make sure the right things are marked as public/private! thx @AnderCover

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).